# Vertical slideshow-type of menu

Tags: jquery, menu, slideshow

[Click me to see schematic](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14193826/schematic_vertical_menu.jpg)

I'm trying to build a simple sliding vertical menu - several divs (#sliderOption_*) inside a div container (sliderContainer). Two arrows (up/down) will control the sliding effect.
I need the divs inside the slider to move 80px (#optionMenu_** height) vertically, up or down. I want the css (namely border radius) for the divs, that are actually inside the visible area of the sliderContainer, to change according to their order (1st, 2nd and 3rd - see picture). The middle item will be the one that will trigger other stuff to happen - the #btn? corresponding should appear for that purpose.
Ive been checking other posts, but can't get a solution for my case...
Html structure:

```
<p id="upBtn">Up</p>
<p id="downBtn">Down</p>

<div id="sliderContainer">
    <div id="optionMenu_1" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 1 <div id="btn1" class="btn">1</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_2" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 2 <div id="btn2" class="btn">2</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_3" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 3 <div id="btn3" class="btn">3</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_4" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 4 <div id="btn6" class="btn">4</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_5" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 5 <div id="btn5" class="btn">5</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_6" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 6 <div id="btn6" class="btn">6</div> </div>
    <div id="optionMenu_7" class="optionMenu"> Option menu 7 <div id="btn7" class="btn">7</div> </div>
</div>
```

I really want the most possible simple thing - no external libraries (if possible).
Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPkZZ/) with all the elements.

Any help appreciated.
Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: i updated my jsfiddle..if you need more explanation tell me and i 'll add more comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your example check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LPkZZ/8/).

i just add one div that contain your `optionMenu` and some jQuery magic.

explanation :

```
<div id="sliderContainer">
    <div class="sliderContainerInside">//add just wrapper to your .optionMenu divs
    ......
    ......
</div>//end div #sliderContainerInside
```

in css add the following :

```
.sliderContainerInside {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
}
#sliderContainer{
      ......
      ......
      position:relative;
}
```

In JS :

```
$("#upBtn").on('click', function () {
    // slide all optionMenu_* up by 80px
    var maxUp = ($('div.optionMenu').length - 3) * 90;//now get the max px that our .sliderContainerInside can have as top(css) value. Notice that (3) represent the number of divs that 'll be visible to the user and (90) is the optionMenu height plus the value of top padding(10)
    if (-maxUp < parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 10) {
        $('.sliderContainerInside').css('top', parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 90 + 'px');
    }
    //console.info($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top') - 80);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was hoping that I could animate it, but it appears your code wasn't built for that. Is it possible to adapt so that I could have the divs animated? Else, could you help on the when-visible css changes? Thanx again.

Comment: Awesome! Simple and brilliant. :) You don't happen to have a solution for the other issue... do you?

Comment: @Pedro sorry i didn't understand the other issue..explain it more

Comment: Well, if you check my schematic you'll see that the 1st item has a specific border radius, the 2nd diferent from the first and the 3rd the same thing. All I need is to be able to give it a different look to each one... kinda like first-child, last-child...